# Talend extract xml for each row

Tags: xml, talend, talend-mdm

In my data source I have records with XML content that I want to extract and duplicate rows :

Data Source

```
id | content 

100 | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RepeaterData><Version /><Items><Item><Years>2018</Years><data>110</data></Item><Item><Years >2019</Years><data>200</data></Item></Items></RepeaterData>
```

I want to get an out put like  :

> 100 | 2018 | 110
>
> 100| 2019 | 200

which component could I use ? Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it :

[image]

First, iterate on your rows, and for each row read the xml column and extract the fields you want from it using `tExtractXMLField`. Then inside the `tMap` retrieve the ID of the current row that was set by `tFlowToIterate`.

And the result :

```
.---+----+----.
|  tLogRow_1  |
|=--+----+---=|
|id |year|data|
|=--+----+---=|
|100|2018|110 |
|100|2019|200 |
'---+----+----'
```

Comment: Thank you iMezouar for your reply, I have a question plz : can I replace the **tFixedFlowInput** by a **tXMLMap** ? I have a flow before to iterate on rows I don't know how to match between my flow to get data and the **tFlowIterate** .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but the easiest way to do this is to first prepare your data and store it in a tHashOutput (that has an ID and XML columns), then in a 2nd subjob do what I suggested in my solution, by replacing tFixedFlowInput_1 with a tHashInput that reads the data you stored in tHashOuptut. This way you don't have to change a lot of things to get it working.

Comment: Happy to help ;)